# Getting information about installed fonts

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, fonts, font-family

I want to retreive information of installed fonts, I've tried by this way:

```
Private Function Get_Installed_Fonts() As Array
    Dim AllFonts As New Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection ' Get the installed fonts collection.
    Dim FontFamilies() As FontFamily = AllFonts.Families()   ' Get an array of the system's font familiies.
    Return FontFamilies ' Return the array
End Function
```

Then I can do...:

```
   For Each Font As FontFamily In Get_Installed_Fonts()
       MsgBox(Font.Name)
   Next
```

But I can't find the way to do this:

```
    For Each Font As FontFamily In Get_Installed_Fonts()
        MsgBox(Font.IsSystemFont)
        MsgBox(Font.OriginalFontName)
        MsgBox(Font.SizeInPoints)
    Next
```

What I'm missing there?

That are the things that I will obtain, and I need too a way to search if a font is installed, for example:

```
If FontsArray.contains("FontName") Then...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the .IsSystemFont, .OriginalFontName, and .SizeInPoints properties are members of the Font class, not FontFamily.  FontFamily is used to create a Font, at which point, you can then use the above language to get the info.

So, you could do...

```
For Each FontFam As FontFamily In Get_Installed_Fonts()
    Dim tFont as new Font(FontFam.Name, 8)
    MsgBox(tFont.IsSystemFont)
    MsgBox(tFont.OriginalFontName)
    MsgBox(tFont.SizeInPoints)
    'tFont = nothing
Next
```

Comment: Don't set variables to Nothing like that in .Net. It used to be necessary in the vb6 era, but for .Net's garbage collector it has either no effect or a _negative_ impact on memory collection.

Comment: Noted and commented out.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function Get_Installed_Fonts() As FontFamily()
    Using AllFonts As New Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection 
        Return AllFonts.Families
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Oops: I misread the question at first. I thought about deleting my answer, but I think I'll leave the code up, because it still has a couple improvements over what you're doing right now.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your modification of the function